# Remove left hand column on product listings page in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

How do you remove the left hand column on product listings page in Magento?

I've looked in the local.xml file but I'm not sure which code I should edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change template of product listing in admin: 
- Catalog->Manage Categories->Your category - tab Custom Design - field - Page Layout

OR

in your design layout xml (local.xml or something else) :

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>left</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

OR

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>left</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

also you can set anpother template in xml:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><name>page/1column.phtml</name></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

see template/page/ for templates.

Answer (score 1):

Using local.xml (read [5 Useful Tricks For Your Magento local.xml](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/5-useful-tricks-for-your-magento-local-xml/))

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <remove name="left"/>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to remove the "left column"  why don't you just change the product listing page to a different layout.   i.e   2column-right.phtml,  1column.phtml,  or 3column.phtml there is no need to physically remove the left column under 99% of most situations just change the layout.

First you need to create or update your local.xml file IF you do not have a local.xml file you can create one in

app->frontend->[Package Name]->[Theme Name]->layout->local.xml

Once this is created you can copy exactly what I have in this post into that file for a start of how to use one.

DO ALL UPDATES THROUGH A LOCAL.XML file not through catalog.xml !! This will make upgrades significantly easier later down the road. Additionally, you will be able to quickly see all changes you have made to your site in one file.

The below example will set the product listing page to 1column

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">

                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
                <!-- Below are examples of different layouts you can use
                <template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template>
                <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
                <template>page/3columns.phtml</template> -->
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Hope this helps and is a guide to some newbies out there.